# BigQuery conversion rate not calculating properly

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get a benchmark dataset in BigQuery. In this dataset I'd like to get data like sessions, bouncerates, new users but most importantly, conversion rates. These do not seem to calculate properly however. The conversion rate gives mainly null values on values that should no be null, and is the values that are not null are wrong unfortunately. I have been googling some answers on a few calculations like bounce rate and it seems to me the calculation for conversion rate should be working like this.

I have also tried different formulae to calculate the conversion rate but in the same format as the code below.

EDIT: there is definitely something wrong in the sessions calculations since it gives less sessions than users

I am using the following code:

```
    SELECT
  actiontimestamp,
  medium,
  source,
  users,
  newUsers,
  sessions,
  ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(pageviews, sessions), 0) AS pages_per_session,
  CASE
    WHEN sessions = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(bounces, sessions), 2)
  END AS bounce_rate,
  ROUND(avgTimeOnSite, 2)
  transactions,
  (SAFE_DIVIDE(transactions, sessions)*100) AS conversion_rate

FROM (
  SELECT
    actiontimestamp,
    medium,
    source,
    COUNT(fullVisitorId) AS users,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS newUsers,
    COUNT(transaction) AS transactions,
    COUNT(pageviews) AS pageviews,
    SUM(bounces) AS bounces,
    SUM(sessions) AS sessions,
    AVG(avgTimeOnSite) AS avgTimeOnSite
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      visitStartTime,
      pageviews,
      actiontimestamp,
      avgTimeOnSite,
      transaction,
      medium,
      source,
      CASE
        WHEN hitNumber = first_interaction THEN bounces
        ELSE 0
      END AS bounces,
      CASE
        WHEN hitNumber = first_hit THEN visits
        ELSE 0
      END AS sessions
    FROM (
      SELECT
        fullVisitorId,
        visitStartTime,
        IFNULL(totals.pageviews,
          0) AS pageviews,
        totals.bounces,
        totals.visits,
        hits.hitNumber,
        MIN(IF(hits.isInteraction IS NOT NULL,
            hits.hitNumber,
            0)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS first_interaction,
        MIN(hits.hitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS first_hit,
        FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), "Europe/London") AS actiontimestamp,
        totals.timeOnSite AS avgTimeOnSite,
        hits.transaction.transactionId AS transaction,
        trafficSource.medium AS medium,
        trafficSource.source AS source
      FROM
        `ga_table_id.ga_sessions_*`,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      WHERE
        _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-01')
        AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-30')))
  GROUP BY
    actiontimestamp,
    medium,
    source)
ORDER BY
  actiontimestamp DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the sessions were defined on different levels the code didn't work. However, when I made 2 separate tables and joined these it worked just fine. The 2 tables had different routes to obtain the sessions which made the calculations work properly.

```
SELECT
  actiontimestamp,
  medium,
  source,
  sessions,
  ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(pageviews,
      sessions), 0) AS pages_per_session,
  CASE
    WHEN sessions = 0 THEN 0
    ELSE ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(bounces,
      sessions), 2)
  END AS bounce_rate,
  ROUND(avgTimeOnSite, 2) AS avgTimeOnSite
FROM (
  SELECT
    actiontimestamp,
    medium,
    source,
    AVG(pageviews) AS pageviews,
    SUM(bounces) AS bounces,
    SUM(sessions) AS sessions,
    AVG(avgTimeOnSite) AS avgTimeOnSite
  FROM (
    SELECT
      fullVisitorId,
      pageviews,
      actiontimestamp,
      avgTimeOnSite,
      medium,
      source,
      CASE
        WHEN hitNumber = first_interaction THEN bounces
        ELSE 0
      END AS bounces,
      CASE
        WHEN hitNumber = first_hit THEN visits
        ELSE 0
      END AS sessions
    FROM (
      SELECT
        fullVisitorId,
        visitStartTime,
        IFNULL(totals.pageviews,
          0) AS pageviews,
        totals.bounces,
        totals.visits,
        totals.newVisits AS newVisits,
        hits.hitNumber,
        MIN(IF(hits.isInteraction IS NOT NULL,
            hits.hitNumber,
            0)) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS first_interaction,
        MIN(hits.hitNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY fullVisitorId, visitStartTime) AS first_hit,
        FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), "Europe/London") AS actiontimestamp,
        totals.timeOnSite AS avgTimeOnSite,
        trafficSource.medium AS medium,
        trafficSource.source AS source
      FROM
        `gatable.ga_sessions_*`,
        UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      WHERE
        _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-01')
        AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-30')))
  GROUP BY
    actiontimestamp,
    medium,
    source)
ORDER BY
  actiontimestamp DESC
```

And the second table would then be :

```
SELECT
  actiontimestamp,
  medium,
  source,
  users,
  newUsers,
  sessions,
  transactions,
  ROUND((SAFE_DIVIDE(transactions,
      sessions)*100), 2) AS conversion_rate
FROM (
  SELECT
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d", TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(SAFE_CAST(visitStartTime AS INT64)), "Europe/London") AS actiontimestamp,
    SUM(totals.transactions) AS transactions,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
    COUNT(totals.newVisits) AS newUsers,
    trafficSource.medium AS medium,
    trafficSource.source AS source
  FROM
    `91775944.ga_sessions_*`

  WHERE
    _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-01')
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', '2018-11-30')
  GROUP BY
    actiontimestamp,
    medium,
    source
   )
```

These tables were then joined on actiontimestamp, medium and source and I got the results that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Should the variables be the other way around?

```
SAFE_DIVIDE(transactions, sessions)
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways, also as (transactions / sessions) * 100 but for some reason i's just not doing it. I think something might be wrong in the sessions calculation because some rows have more users than sessions which should never be the case

Comment: I think that's because you are defining a session as the first hit. Therefore if a session didn't start at the same time as your actiontimestamp sessions will be 0 but users will be 1?

Comment: Thanks Bobby, you are right. I have actually split it up into 2 queries now and joined them afterwards which works fine because the session definition is required differently for some reason. (my knowledge is not yet that advanced unfortunately)